# Electric field inside hollow metallic sphere which is not closed

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Suppose I have a charged hollow metallic sphere. It is sure that the electric field inside the sphere is zero, in static case. ( I got explanation for this from the previous discussions in this site). Accourding to my knowledge, it is because the surface is closed and is equipotential. Now suppose I make a hole in its surface so that the surface is no longer closed. Is then electric field appear in it? Or what happened then?

Comment: The electric field inside the sphere is only zero if there are no charges inside the sphere. If you make a hole into the sphere, the electric field will penetrate, but not too much, as long as the hole is small. One can shield electrostatic fields quite nicely even with relatively coarse meshes, as long as one can afford to be several mesh sizes away from the mesh.

Comment: @CuriousOne Do you know a quantitative version of that answer? that's something I haven't seen before.